# Циклы и Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await, promise

Есть цепочка `промисов`, первый берет `id` пользователей из `БД`, потом по нему нужно достать его группы, и имена конструкторов. И это все может быть в нескольких экземплярах. Как следствие - циклы в циклах. В конечном счете получаю объект только одного пользователя

```js
async(takeIds()
  .then(ids => {
    // console.log("ids", ids);
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      data.id = ids[i];
      await (takeIdvk(ids[i])
        .then(idm => {
          data.idvk = idm;
          takeIdg(data.id)
            .then(res => {
              takeNamesCycle(res, data)
                .then(data => {
                  console.log("data", data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }));
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }));
```

И функция `takeNamesCycle`, так как она отличается от остальных (в остальных простые запросы к `БД`):

```js
var takeNamesCycle = async(function(arr, obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var idg = arr[i];
      await (takeNames(arr[i])
        .then(names => {
          obj.idg[idg] = names;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }));
    }
    resolve(obj);
  });
});
```

Может, можно как-то упростить это все? Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала несколько полезных ссылок на документацию: [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function), [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Возможно я что-то не то предлагаю, но я бы переписал код вот так (обернув в `async` функцию `main`):

```
async function main() {
  let ids = await takeIds();
  for (let id of ids) {
    data.id = id;
    let idm = await takeIdvk(id);
    data.idvk = idm;
    let res = await takeIdg(id);
    let data = takeNamesCycle(res, data);
    console.log('data', data);
  }
}
```

Это в предположении, что у вас существуют следующие функции:

```
async function takeIds() { ... }
async function takeIdvk() { ... }
async function takeIdg() { ... }
```

Вот вариант с «обработкой» ошибок — оборачиваем весь код вот так:

```
try {
    // код
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

В вашем случае:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    let ids = await takeIds();
    for (let id of ids) {
      data.id = id;
      let idm = await takeIdvk(id);
      data.idvk = idm;
      let res = await takeIdg(id);
      let data = takeNamesCycle(res, data);
      console.log('data', data);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Основную мысль уловил, пробую релизовать, но все равно не ждет, я так понимаю, что дело в этих функциях... Они имеют следующий вид:
`var takeIds = async(function(ids) {
 var sql = "SELECT idm FROM cube.mr GROUP BY idm";
 con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {console.log("Err in select idm from mr "+err)}
     var results = [];
     for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ids[i] = result[i]['idm'];
     }
  console.log("results", ids);
  return ids;
 });
});`

Comment: @ФилиппПавлик, если честно ни разу не встречал синтаксис `async(function(){...})`, возможно он не является корректным. А вы не можете переписать примерно как у меня в ответе (то есть `async function имя(){}`)?

Comment: Я что хочу сказать, что результат запроса в колбеке, который находится в этой асинхронной функции, и там он должен обработаться или вернуться просто

Comment: `async function main () {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
`
Цитата из терминала))
Подчеркивает слово function

Comment: @ФилиппПавлик, странно, [вот тут в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) точно так же пишут

Comment: Вот я изначально ее тоже по ней пробовал... Может ли дело быть в том, что это серверная часть, а не клиентская? А на счет синтаксиса со скобками - это [отсюда](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncawait)

Comment: @ФилиппПавлик насколько я понимаю это библиотека, которая была нужна пока в nodejs не добавили встроенную поддержку async/await (это произошло в Node.js 7.6). Соответственно (вроде бы) после Node.js 7.6 эта библиотека уже не нужна

Comment: Хах, посмотрел свою версию - 4.2.6(((( Вопрос как к более опытному: обновлять или нет? Конец проекта просто, и не будет ли непредсказуемых вещей?

Comment: @ФилиппПавлик если честно я не очень подхожу на роль более опытного... всегда выступаю за обновление всего чего только возможно, но большие проекты не делал, поэтому ничего не смогу посоветовать. Можете задать новый вопрос (хотя его наверно закроют), либо спросить в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Да у меня тоже пунктик на обновление ПО, но чет я как-то пропустил этот момент, когда начинал проект. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Слушай, а есть идеи, как реализовать? Может через колбекхел?)) 
Основная идея: получить сначала пользователей, потом их группы, потом названия последней обложки для каждой группы. 2 цикла точно надо, один по пользователям, второй по группам. И после каждого полученного имени обложки запустить другой скрипт, он рабочий, просто туда нужно входные данные кинуть id, idgroup и name

Comment: @ФилиппПавлик может написать функцию для каждого действия, у которой будет два параметра, второй параметр это callback, в качестве него будет передаваться следующая функция